# PHP setting JSON values to Textboxes

Tags: php, ajax, json

This is the html file.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
                return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
    {
         var doc = window.document.createElement("doc");
         var a = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

     document.getElementById("stuname").value=a.first;
         document.getElementById("branch").value=a.second;
         document.getElementById("year").value=a.third;
         document.getElementById("category").value=a.four;
      }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","test2.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
Roll Number:<br>
<input type="text" name="rollno" id="rollno" onblur="showUser(this.value)">
<br>
Student Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="stuname" id="stuname" value="">
Branch:<br>
<input type="text" name="branch" id="branch" value="">
Year:<br>
<input type="text" name="year" id="year" value="">
Category:<br>
<input type="text" name="category" id="category" value="">
</form>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

test2.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$q = $_GET['q'];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","neel","sitams");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$sql="SELECT rollno,stuname,branch,category FROM studet where rollno='".$q."' and academic='2014-2015'";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  while ($obj=mysqli_fetch_object($result))
    {
     $queryResult[] = $obj->rollno;
     $queryResult[] = $obj->stuname;
     $queryResult[] = $obj->branch;
     $queryResult[] = $obj->category;
    }
}

$textboxValue1 = $queryResult[0];
$textboxValue2 = $queryResult[1];
$textboxValue3 = $queryResult[2];
$textboxValue4 = $queryResult[3];
echo json_encode(array('first'=>$textboxValue1,'second'=>$textboxValue2,'third'=>$textboxValue3,'four'=>$textboxValue4));
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I could not able to load values to the text boxes where is fault. Even I have seen stackoverflow but I could not able to get it. when I type test2.php by passing rollno value to q it will display data but when I pass a value from html it could not able to set the values to the textbox fields.

Comment: did you tryed console.info(a) in order to see what you are getting from ajax call

Comment: What is the html code for in test2.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove any html tags from test2.php  . An ajax document does not need any html tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi this one will be helpful to you .
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="showUser('ok');" value="click to ru me" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function showUser(str) 
{
    if (str=="") 
    {
      return;
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
        else {  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        { 
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
            {
                //var doc = window.document.createElement("doc");
                var parsed = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                for(var x in parsed)
                {
                    var First=parsed[x].first;
                    var Second=parsed[x].second;
                    var Third=parsed[x].third;
                    var Fourth=parsed[x].fourth;
                    console.log("first="+First+" second="+Second+" third="+Third+" fourth="+Fourth);

                     document.getElementById("stuname").value=parsed[x].first;
                     document.getElementById("branch").value=parsed[x].second;
                     document.getElementById("year").value=parsed[x].third;
                     document.getElementById("category").value=parsed[x].fourth;
                }

            }
         }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","phpex.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }

}
</script>

<input type="text" id="stuname" />
<input type="text" id="branch" />
<input type="text" id="year" />
<input type="text" id="category" />
</body>
</html>

Ajax File Name phpex.php . ajax page code is below

<?php
echo '[{"first":"1111","second":"2222","third":"3333","fourth":"4444"}]';
?>
```